# React-native app is being restarted on every navigation when integrated with native app

Tags: javascript, android, react-native, react-native-navigation

We're trying to integrate a new React Native app to an existing native Android app. Following the RN official [docs](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/integration-with-existing-apps) we managed to get it working but with some issues regarding the navigation.

We've native and non-native (JS) screens, and we need a good way to navigate between all screens regardless if a screen is native or not.

We tried to adopt [native-navigation](https://github.com/airbnb/native-navigation) and [react-native-navigation](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation) to see if any address our issue but none of them actually worked.

Currently, we have registered all our RN screens like this:

```
const provide = (store, Screen) => {
      return props => (
        <Provider store={store}>
          <Screen {...props} />
        </Provider>
      );
    };

    const store = configureStore();

    AppRegistry.registerComponent('Home', () => provide(store, HomeComponent));
```

We also created a Native Module we call "Navigator" that has navigation method called `openComponent` that accepts screen name and its props. Here is how the implementation of `openComponent` looks:

```
// our native module code ...
     @ReactMethod
     public void openComponent(String name, String extra) {

         try {
             Intent intent = new Intent(this.getReactApplicationContext(), MyReactActivity.class);
             intent.putExtra("moduleName", name);
             intent.putExtra("extra", extra);

             getCurrentActivity().startActivityForResult(intent, 0);
         }
         catch (Exception e) {
             e.printStackTrace();
             Crashlytics.logException(e.getCause());
         }
     }
```

Then whenever we want to navigate on the RN side we simply call our custom navigator with the target screen props.

**The problem** with the current approach is that the RN part is being restarted whenever we navigate to RN-based screens which causes the Redux store to be empty.

Here how our "onCreate" method looks like for our ReactActivity.java class:

```
@Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        Bundle initialProperties = new Bundle();
        initialProperties.putString("loginToken", HJSession.getSession().getSessionId());
        initialProperties.putString("username", HJSession.getSession().getUserName());
        initialProperties.putString("userId", HJSession.getSession().getUserId().toString());

        String moduleName = "topics";
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

        if (bundle != null) {
            moduleName = bundle.getString("moduleName");
            try {
                String extra = bundle.getString("extra");
                initialProperties.putString("extra", extra);
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                Crashlytics.logException(e.getCause());
            }
        }

        mReactRootView = new ReactRootView(this);
        mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
                .setApplication(getApplication())
                .setJSMainModulePath("index")
                .addPackages(Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
                        new MainReactPackage(),
                        new RNFirebasePackage(),
                        new RNFirebaseMessagingPackage(),
                        new RNFirebaseNotificationsPackage(),
                        new RNI18nPackage(),
                        new VectorIconsPackage(),
                        new HJRNPackages(),
                        new NativeNavigationPackage()
                ))
                .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
                .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
                .build();

        mReactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, moduleName, initialProperties);

        setContentView(mReactRootView);
    }
```

Comment: You are experiencing Redux change whenever you go from Native to React right? or within React Navigation?  If you're changing from N to RN then shouldn't you persist your Redux state locally? I'm just asking for clarification.

Comment: @AshwinMothilal Well, in our case it's not  suitable to persist our state locally (on hard disk) on every navigation. But the RN part shouldn't be restarted anyway, right?

Comment: You didn't answer this part yet, You are experiencing Redux change whenever you go from Native to React right? or within React Navigation?

Comment: Yes, we experience reload when we go from Native to React and also from React to another React screen since we are using the same "openComponent" function mentioned in the original question above, Thanks

Comment: I wish you upload a reproduction repository for your question on `gitlab` or `github`

Answer (score 4):

Actually, for your question case, you should upload a little tiny scale of your project that has this issue on Gitlab or Github and put its link here, Hence we could help better.

Indeed, I'm a `JavaScript`, `React`, `React Native` developer and I cannot help anybody in the native side, But definitely, I believe you and your colleagues choose the wrong way for your application.

`React Native` is an unstable `JavaScript` project that has unstable native codes that are changing in time, so you should write all of your features just by using `JavaScript`. Just like [Sophie Albert](https://twitter.com/sophiebits) said in [this article](http://facebook.github.io/react-native/blog/2018/06/14/state-of-react-native-2018), They wanna make a big break change to `React Native`, So, It is better all of the codes to be written in `JavaScript` not native (Java, Objective C).

At first, I believe your choosing on [`react-native-navigation`](https://github.com/wix/react-native-navigation) was wrong. Why you do not use [`react-navigation`](https://github.com/react-navigation/react-navigation)?

Because 99.7% of `react-navigation` based on `JavaScript` and changing native sides by Facebook teams, do not affect your project and development and debugging is very easy. absolutely, you can use every trend library like `Redux`, because of your project based on `JavaScript`.

My colleagues and I are developing a large scale `React Native` application for [Sheypoor](https://www.sheypoor.com/), except the splash screen all of the app based on `JavaScript` and in our inputs tests we didn't get even one crash or error or unwanted restart.

If it is possible for you, roll back your navigation to a full `JavaScript` navigation library like `react-navigation` which we chose. If you uploaded a reproduction repository I could help you better than this situation. but I put some of our code structure to help you for roll back to `react-navigation`:

The `index.js` of our project:

```
import { AppRegistry } from 'react-native';
import App from './app/App';
import { name as appName } from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

The root file of our app, the `App.js` file:

```
import React from 'react';
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
import RootNavigation from './RootNavigation';
import { onNavigationStateChange } from './utils/routes';
import configureStore from './redux/configureStore';

const store = configureStore();

const App = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <RootNavigation onNavigationStateChange={onNavigationStateChange} />
  </Provider>
);

export default App;
```

The `RootNavigation.js` file, but it is for our earlier commits not now. I don't put the newer version because of its complexities:

```
import { createSwitchNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { Loading, Dashboard, SignInStack, ListingManagement } from './screens';

const RootNavigation = createSwitchNavigator(
  {
    Loading,
    SignInStack,
    Dashboard,
    ListingManagement
  },
  {
    initialRouteName: 'SignInStack'
  }
);

export default RootNavigation;
```

And at last, the earlier version of `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "sheypoor",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "android": "npx react-native run-android",
    "ios": "npx react-native run-ios",
    "physical-android": "react-native bundle --platform android --dev false --entry-file index.js --bundle-output android/app/src/main/assets/index.android.bundle --assets-dest android/app/src/main/res",
    "test": "jest",
    "eslint": "eslint .",
    "clean": "react-native-clean-project",
    "pre-commit": "lint-staged"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.js": [
      "eslint --fix ."
    ]
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "formik": "^1.3.0",
    "lint-staged": "^7.3.0",
    "prop-types": "^15.6.2",
    "react": "16.5.0",
    "react-native": "0.57.1",
    "react-native-confirmation-code-field": "^1.2.2",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^5.0.0",
    "react-navigation": "^2.16.0",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "yup": "^0.26.6"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-eslint": "^9.0.0",
    "babel-jest": "23.6.0",
    "babel-plugin-module-resolver": "^3.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-root-import": "^6.1.0",
    "eslint": "^5.5.0",
    "eslint-config-airbnb": "^17.1.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^3.0.1",
    "eslint-import-resolver-babel-plugin-root-import": "^1.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-flowtype": "^2.50.0",
    "eslint-plugin-import": "^2.14.0",
    "eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y": "^6.1.1",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^2.6.2",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.11.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^3.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-sort-imports-es6-autofix": "^0.3.0",
    "flow-bin": "^0.78.0",
    "jest": "23.6.0",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.45.6",
    "prettier": "^1.14.3",
    "react-native-clean-project": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-config": "^0.11.5",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.5.0",
    "redux-devtools-extension": "^2.13.5"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  },
  "rnpm": {
    "assets": [
      "./app/assets/fonts"
    ]
  }
}
```

With these codes and configurations, we didn't give even one error.

Answer (score 0):

In the `ReactActivity.java` one can check for `Bundle savedInstanceState`

... in order to control when the React application is being instanced:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    /* it's always NULL on first run */
    if (savedInstanceState == null) {

        Bundle initialProperties = new Bundle();
        initialProperties.putString("loginToken", HJSession.getSession().getSessionId());
        initialProperties.putString("username", HJSession.getSession().getUserName());
        initialProperties.putString("userId", HJSession.getSession().getUserId().toString());

        String moduleName = "topics";
        Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras();

        if (bundle != null) {
            moduleName = bundle.getString("moduleName");
            try {
                String extra = bundle.getString("extra");
                initialProperties.putString("extra", extra);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Crashlytics.logException(e.getMessage());
                Log.e("ReactActivity", e.getMessage());
            }
        }

        mReactRootView = new ReactRootView(this);
        mReactInstanceManager = ReactInstanceManager.builder()
            .setApplication(getApplication())
            .setJSMainModulePath("index")
            .addPackages(Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
                new MainReactPackage(),
                new RNFirebasePackage(),
                new RNFirebaseMessagingPackage(),
                new RNFirebaseNotificationsPackage(),
                new RNI18nPackage(),
                new VectorIconsPackage(),
                new HJRNPackages(),
                new NativeNavigationPackage()
            ))
            .setUseDeveloperSupport(BuildConfig.DEBUG)
            .setInitialLifecycleState(LifecycleState.RESUMED)
            .build();

        mReactRootView.startReactApplication(mReactInstanceManager, moduleName, initialProperties);
        setContentView(mReactRootView);
    }
}
```

Comment: Upvote, but in `React Native` it is better not use native solutions. thanks for your help.

Comment: @AngelHotxxx it's not the question what is better (...), but how to prevent the React app from restarting (the reason is, that `onCreate()` may run more than just once).